# Rkhunter scan issue

Tags: rkhunter

I have a few false positive scans on my rkhunter. However I did a scan today
and these results do kinda worry me, I have 8 warnings now. I will post the
warnings that Im not sure about.

```
 /usr/sbin/runlevel                                       [ Warning 
 /usr/bin/sudo                                            [ Warning 
  /usr/bin/systemd                                         [ Warning ]
  /usr/bin/systemctl                                       [ Warning ]
 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd                                 [ Warning ]
```

These are the new warnings that showed up. I looked into the log and found this.

```
[23:25:11]   /usr/sbin/runlevel                              [ Warning ]
[23:25:11] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[23:25:11]          File: /usr/sbin/runlevel
[23:25:11]          Current hash: f48396b4d8fbf906a0a12ec5f9581a119fe266b0d61919c251e8320bd099327a
[23:25:11]          Stored hash : a9c198f924de92ab40633d345c55b6e84986e6e58f5569220871af3edeaca069
[23:25:11]          Current inode: 25954758    Stored inode: 25954035
[23:25:11]          Current file modification time: 1679322728 (20-Mar-2023 10:32:08)
[23:25:11]          Stored file modification time : 1677761882 (02-Mar-2023 07:58:02)


[23:25:18]   /usr/bin/sudo                                   [ Warning ]
[23:25:18] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[23:25:18]          File: /usr/bin/sudo
[23:25:18]          Current hash: 7d3c2983ad2f278d9e799b5792f13f57bf890bd3b03d10b36e53bf0b6677895e
[23:25:18]          Stored hash : 49278c0ebbc089cc04cfa6136a8011519fbaca9d99106443212e43c2141a7ff9
[23:25:18]          Current inode: 25957682    Stored inode: 25953068
[23:25:18]          Current file modification time: 1680544844 (03-Apr-2023 14:00:44)
[23:25:18]          Stored file modification time : 1677679177 (01-Mar-2023 08:59:37)


[23:25:19] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[23:25:19]          File: /usr/bin/systemd
[23:25:19]          Current hash: 477209848fabcaf52c060d98287f880845cb07fc9696216dbcfe9b6ea8e72bcd
[23:25:19]          Stored hash : c76a78e1572f62e0b28e0e5c459bd475917eb92177bdbeedf965d22c261b0f82
[23:25:19]          Current inode: 25957781    Stored inode: 25956458
[23:25:19]          Current file modification time: 1679322728 (20-Mar-2023 10:32:08)
[23:25:19]          Stored file modification time : 1677761882 (02-Mar-2023 07:58:02)
[23:25:19]   /usr/bin/systemctl                              [ Warning ]
[23:25:19] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[23:25:19]          File: /usr/bin/systemctl
[23:25:19]          Current hash: f48396b4d8fbf906a0a12ec5f9581a119fe266b0d61919c251e8320bd099327a
[23:25:19]          Stored hash : a9c198f924de92ab40633d345c55b6e84986e6e58f5569220871af3edeaca069
[23:25:19]          Current inode: 25953751    Stored inode: 25954081
[23:25:19]          Current size: 1119856    Stored size: 1115760
[23:25:19]          Current file modification time: 1679322728 (20-Mar-2023 10:32:08)
[23:25:19]          Stored file modification time : 1677761882 (02-Mar-2023 07:58:02)


23:25:22]   /usr/lib/systemd/systemd                        [ Warning ]
[23:25:22] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[23:25:22]          File: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
[23:25:22]          Current hash: 477209848fabcaf52c060d98287f880845cb07fc9696216dbcfe9b6ea8e72bcd
[23:25:22]          Stored hash : c76a78e1572f62e0b28e0e5c459bd475917eb92177bdbeedf965d22c261b0f82
[23:25:22]          Current inode: 25954768    Stored inode: 25956371
[23:25:22]          Current file modification time: 1679322728 (20-Mar-2023 10:32:08)
[23:25:22]          Stored file modification time : 1677761882 (02-Mar-2023 07:58:02)
```

I really need help on this to find out if this is a false positive or not. Systemd
does concern me along with the other warnings. Thanks.

Update

A user told me to look at recent updates and I remember I did do some updates linux wanted me to do in the past 2 days and I found in history of updates some lines libsystemd0, systemd-coredump, libnss-systemd,systemd, libpam-systemd and other updates. Seeing all these updates involving systemd is a sure sign of false positives. I need to look at my update history more after these scans. Im gonna look at the man page in rkhunter to restore every warning to OK. Its solved.

Comment: did you upgrade your system recently? that could easily explain why the hashes on those files have changed.

Comment: **If** on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/... you may be interested in running `debsums -xa` instead. I've been using `debsums -ce` in the past to find out which _configuration_ files have changed (so *you* don't want `-e`!).

Answer (score 1):

Its usual when the system got updated using `apt-get` or `apt`. Try the scan again after updating the rkhunter file properties database using either,

```
sudo rkhunter --propupd
```

or,

```
sudo rkhunter --update --propupd
```